# Write 2D List to File Error: System.InvalidOperationException:

Tags: c#, collections, filewriter, streamwriter.write

I have a List double [,] array.
When i try to below code c# to write 2d double list array to file i got error.
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'"

```
public void Write(List<double[,]> arrays, string filepath)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath))
            {
                foreach (double[,] array in arrays)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < array.GetLength(0))
                    {
                        string line = "";
                        int o = 0;
                        while (o < array.GetLength(1))
                        {
                            line = line + array[i, o];
                            if (o + 1 < array.GetLength(1))
                            {
                                line = line + " ";
                            }
                            o++;
                        }
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe this might help you as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-serialize-an-object

Comment: how to do you want the array to be written to the file?

Comment: @styx With a space for each element and row by row.

Comment: @K.Ense what have you tried so far? google is your best friend

Comment: @nagyben How will I convert use my 2d double array instead of myobject?

Comment: @styx i added what i used.

Comment: the code works fine to me,by the error,  it looks like you are modifying the collection somewhere else where write hasn't finished yet

Comment: @styx you are absolutely right, thanks. Pls add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine to me, by the error, it looks like you are modifying the collection somewhere else where `write()` function hasn't finished yet

more on that you can find [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/02/28/enumerating-collections-that-change-in-csharp/)